# Exit after res.status() called from another function in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I coded a simple express.js app with a validate the post before executing other stuffs. So, I looking for the checkPostExists() function to stop when the function returns a res.status() without doing other stuffs.

Here's my code as it stands now:

```
function checkPostExists(req, res) {
    const post = posts.find((post) => post.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

    if (!post) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            msg: `No post with the id of ${req.params.id}`,
        });
    }
}

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    checkPostExists(req, res);

    res.json(posts.filter((post) => post.id === parseInt(req.params.id)));
});
```

When GET request `localhost:3000/api/posts/4`, it response correctly from checkPostExists function.

```
{
    "msg": "No post with the id of 4"
}
```

But got this error after the response.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\routes\posts.js:26:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\truethari\Documents\GitHub\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

If res.status() does not stop the function, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal programming logic.  You need a return value from `checkPostExists()` that the caller can use to know what to do next.  Right now, you have no return value so the caller doesn't know if you've already sent a response or not.

Normally, I would not send a response from multiple places because it creates this readability and maintainability problem about whether a response has been sent yet or not.  Further, it doesn't give the caller control over exactly what is sent.

But, if you're trying to use `checkPostExists()` in lots of request handlers and put as much common code as you can into that function, you can do something like this:

```
function checkPostExists(req, res) {
    const post = posts.find((post) => post.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

    if (!post) {
        res.status(404).json({
            msg: `No post with the id of ${req.params.id}`,
        });
    }
    return post;
}

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    if (checkPostExists(req, res)) {
        res.json(posts.filter((post) => post.id === parseInt(req.params.id)));
    }
});
```

This adds a return value to `checkPostExists()` which tells the caller if the post exists and whether a 404 error has already been sent.  The caller, then needs to check that return value to act accordingly.

---

Note, a cleaner solution would be using a middleware implementation:

```
function checkPostExists(req, res, next) {
    const post = posts.find((post) => post.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

    if (!post) {
        res.status(404).json({
            msg: `No post with the id of ${req.params.id}`,
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
    
}

router.get("/:id", checkPostExists, (req, res) => {
    res.json(posts.filter((post) => post.id === parseInt(req.params.id)));
});
```

This only actually calls your route handler code IF `checkPostExists()` calls `next()`.

You can then use this `checkPostExists` middleware in ANY route that wants to enforce this pre-check.  You would even enforce it at a router level so it automatically applied to all routes in the router.